# Merge pgf plot and gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I have one plot created with Gnuplot (first plot below, over-approximation of some ground truth) and another one with PGF-plot (second plot, depicts a sample true trajectory) and I'd like to insert the graph from the PGF-plot into the Gnuplot such that the thin line lays over the wider blue area. I've been looking for similar problems but was unable to find any, is there a way to "merge" both plots into one?

[image] [image]

Comment: Could you maybe provide the code for both plots?

Comment: I wanted to, but the only problem is that the source code for the first plot exceeds the character limit. But here's a [temporary file sharing link](https://file.io/A6rZunbO2NFO) if you don't mind.

Comment: I see, so you produced the both plots above with some software that generated a file with a lot of basic PGF macros. In this case, it is a bit complicated to merge both pictures. You could try to identify the path that represents the plot of the right diagram and overlay this onto the left diagram. May I ask for the formulas that are basis for both plots? It might be easier to recreate everything using a proper PGF plot.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this! The gnuplot is created using some intricate computations based on flowpipe construction in C++, therefore I unfortunately cannot simply provide a formula. But for the PGF plot on the right, I plotted it in Python using two ODEs, x'=-0.5x+15 for the increasing part and x'=-0.5x for the decreasing part, and a starting condition x(0)=20. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, it is not possible to make the first graph in LaTeX, -so it should be imported in a pdf/svg/image and the second graph drawn on top like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{example-image}};
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm, height=10cm, scale only axis,
xmin=-0.1, xmax=2.6,
ymin=16, ymax=24,
]
\addplot[red, ultra thick, domain=0:2.5, samples=200] {x<0.75?4*x+20:(x<1?-26*x+42:6*x+10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image with graph on top]